# Android: make paging effect

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-canvas, paging

I would like to develop an application, which has a part, when I have to print a long text on the screen. My question is: What layout or view or ? are you recommend for Me, if I want to make paging effect? Some text could reserve more pages, and I would like to scroll between these pages with an effect like e-book readers does it. What shall I prefer? Webview? TextView with modifications? Canvas? Or What?
Please give me tips. (I just need some direction to where shall I start now)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're refering to the ViewPager : 
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

If so, I recommend you to follow this training and come back on StackOverFlow if you have a problem, with some code, or something you've tried and hasn't worked.